# Can unpublished Microsoft Teams connectors be owned/registered to a tenant rather than an individual?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

It seems that Microsoft Teams conectors have to be registered/owned by an individual's microsoft account (unless they are published to the app store), whilst the Microsoft Teams app that uses them, can exist independently. Thus, if the individual who developed the connectors leaves the company, and their account is closed, all the company's connectors will stop working. Then new connectors will have to be created and the existing Teams app manifests will have to be modified. This will cause a problem for our clients who rely on them.

Is this correct and is there anything we can do about it?

I understand that the connectors and app could be published to the app store, but it is a private app, intended solely for use by our selves and our clients, so we don't feel it is appropriate to publish it.

The connectors are generated through the Connectors Developer Dashboard, https://outlook.office.com/connectors/publish and are owned/registered to the developer's Microsoft account. We use them to send notifications from our custom web app to our clients' channels in Microsoft Teams.

Comment: Could you please refer below doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-creating#commands-to-enable-or-disable-connectors

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I can't find anything in that link "Commands to enable or disable connectors", or the rest of the document, that answers the question. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: To enable connectors for Teams, run the following commands:
Set-OrganizationConfig -ConnectorsEnabled:$true
Set-OrganizationConfig -ConnectorsEnabledForTeams:$true
Set-OrganizationConfig -ConnectorsActionableMessagesEnabled:$true

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Thank you, but I am not trying to enable connectors in Teams. The connectors are already in use, across multiple Tenants, as part of our Teams app. The problem is (as I understand it) that when my Microsoft account is closed, the connectors I have created will cease to exist and will no longer work for our clients. Is there a way to change the ownership of the connectors or somehow make them persist independently of my MS Account (In the same way that the Teams apps do), without publishing an app? It seem odd that the teams apps will continue to work, but not the connectors.

Comment: This looks like a new feature request. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in Teams [UserVoice](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472). 

Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience. Some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, and your good ideas will be very helpful for them to improve the service.